# How to add attendees with Google Calendar API on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, calendar, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to add attendees to an event in Google Calendar with the API.

Using the following method which is close to the update function won't do the work and removes all old attendees instead.

Here's the code:

```js
const attendees = (id) => {
    var event = gapi.client.calendar.events.get({
        "calendarId": 'primary',
        "eventId": id
    });

    // Example showing a change in the location
    event.attendees = "rayen.mechergui@esprit.tn"

    var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.patch({
        'calendarId': 'primary',
        'eventId': id,
        'resource': event
    });

    request.execute(function(event) {
        console.log(event);
    });
}
```

Here is an example of a returned event :

```js
{
    'summary': 'Event Summary',
    'location': 'Event location',
    'description': 'Event Description',
    'start': {
        'dateTime': '2021-08-03T02:17:00+01:00',
        'timeZone': 'UTC'
    },
    'end': {
        'dateTime': '2021-08-04T00:20:00+01:00',
        'timeZone': 'UTC'
    },
    'recurrence': [
        'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=1'
    ],
    'attendees': [{
            'email': 'rayen.mechergui@esprit.tn'
        },
        {
            'email': 'mecherguirayen@gmail.com'
        },
    ],
    'reminders': {
        'useDefault': false,
        'overrides': [{
                'method': 'email',
                'minutes': 10
            },
            {
                'method': 'popup',
                'minutes': 20
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Events.patch](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/patch) method states clearly that:

> The field values you specify replace the existing values. Fields that you don’t specify in the request remain unchanged. Array fields, if specified, overwrite the existing arrays; this discards any previous array elements.

So when you add the field "attendees" it will replace the existing attendees Array.

---

You should use the [Events.update](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/update) method, which does not delete previous attendees when you add new.

Comment: Is there any other way to add attendees whithout losing the others ? i tried update , push and put but they didn't do so